# rails t function showing i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I'm working on my first refinerycms project and there is this line in the footer:

```
<%= t('.copyright', :year => Time.now.year, :site_name => Refinery::Core.site_name) %>
```

It's displaying this on my site:

```
i18n: Copyright
```

Where does the i18n come from and is the t function needed?

EDIT:

My /config/locales/en.yml contains the code below. Do i need to add something to this or would it best just to remove the t() tag?

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
```

Comment: I18n is the internationalization gem that is packaged with Rails. The `t` method, if I recall correctly, is just an alias or helper method to the I18n `translate` method. I'm not sure why you're seeing `i18n: Copyright` though. Do you have a translation out there for Copyright?

Comment: I don't know. Where would i look?

Comment: In your en.yml file you'll need a copyright: "Copyright". Basically t() just uses the tag you give it in your yml to look up the corresponding value, and uses that as your translation. If you don't need to worry about translations, you can just get rid of the t().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i18n it's the internationalization library that comes with Rails, wich helps for having translation for diferent locations in your Rails app.

t() it's just the call for translate, I think it's an alias actually.

You should have a yaml file in your locales folder where there is a copyright, wich needs a year and a site_name.

I guess you changed the location so there is no translation, since refineryCms should be english only.

Comment: I've edited my question. Please see my updated/clarified question.

Comment: This is a good point - I guess that we should consider moving the copyright key more global than it is currently (where it relies on being inside the footer).

Answer (score 5):

About your second question - `t('.copyright')` expecting for proper key under your folders tree structure ( because it has `.` at the beggining ). For example, if you have a footer under your shared folder ( full path will be `app/views/shared/_footer.erb` ), then you should have next structure for your YML:

```
en:
  shared:
    footer:
      copyright: "All rights reserved. (c) %{site_name} at %{year}"
```

`%{site_name}` and `%{year}` are interpolation's placeholders for your values at:

```
<%= t('.copyright', :year => Time.now.year, :site_name => Refinery::Core.site_name) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `t` method is an alias for the `translate` method. Both of them can be found in [ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html).

Assume `options = { :year => Time.now.year, :site_name => Refinery::Core.site_name }`.

Since the key being passed starts with a period, the call to `t('.copyright', options)` which is in the `refinery/_footer.html.erb` view will actually be calling `I18n.translate('refinery.footer.copyright', options)`.

Now, the default English translation for the key `refinery.footer.copyright` can be found [here](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/blob/2.0.10/core/config/locales/en.yml). It is `"Copyright © %{year} %{site_name}"`. If you want to override that value, then I think the best way to do that will be to set that key in your `config/locales/en.yml` file.

```
en:
  refinery:
    footer:
      copyright: "My custom copyright text"
```